# php discussion board doesn't post comments

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a discussion board using php. With the code, all the username, data & time, and comment are stored into the data.txt file specified in the code; however, I can't get what's in data.txt to appear on the page. I think I might have the echo() part of the code wrong or the delimiters are messed up.

```
<?php
   $filename = "users.txt";
   $delim="*@*";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (!($fp = fopen($filename, 'a+'))) { 
        echo("Error: Could not open $filename for writing."); 
} 
    else{
        $thePost=$_POST['post'];
        $username=$_POST['uname'];
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
        $string=(date('c')."\n".$username."\n".$thePost."\n*@*"); 
        fwrite($fp, $string); 
        $accounts = explode("\n", $theData);
        fclose($fp);
    } 
}

    ?>



<html>
    <body>
<h1> Discuss </h1> </br> </br>

<form method="post" action="discussion.php">
    Name: <input name="uname" type="text" /> </br>
    <textarea name="post" rows=4 cols=60>Add comment</textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment"/>
</form>
<?php

if (!($fp = fopen($filename, 'a+'))) { 
        echo("Error: Could not open $filename for writing."); 
} 
    else{
        fread($fp, filesize($filename));
        $accounts = explode("*@*", $theData);
        fclose($fp);
        for ($i = 0; $i <count($accounts); $i++){
                echo($i);
                echo($accounts[$i]);
            } 
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong/why the user/data/time/comment won't post anything on the page. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the contents of data.txt?

Comment: @slapyo 2014-10-11T15:30:33-04:00
bob
this is my comment
*@*

Comment: Do you want just one line of the file, or do you want the individual pieces (date, name, post)?

Comment: @slapyo I would need the individual pieces. I'm assuming that means that I need to put the information in an array, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. There is an additional newline inserted on `$string` at the end otherwise the next line would append to the end of the @. After that, just explode on the newline in your loop. The problem you may run into is if the post contains a new line. You might want to look at using a different delimiter that would probably not occur in the post. Putting this into a database would probably be a better idea, though I'm not sure what exactly you're doing. But this should get you the info you're looking for.

```
<?php
   $filename = "users.txt";
   $delim="*@*";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (!($fp = fopen($filename, 'a+'))) { 
        echo("Error: Could not open $filename for writing."); 
} 
    else{
        $thePost=$_POST['post'];
        $username=$_POST['uname'];
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
        $string=(date('c')."\n".$username."\n".$thePost."\n*@*\n"); 
        fwrite($fp, $string); 
        $accounts = explode("\n", $theData);
        fclose($fp);
    } 
}

    ?>



<html>
    <body>
<h1> Discuss </h1> </br> </br>

<form method="post" action="discussion.php">
    Name: <input name="uname" type="text" /> </br>
    <textarea name="post" rows=4 cols=60>Add comment</textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Comment"/>
</form>
<?php

if (!($fp = fopen($filename, 'a+'))) { 
        echo("Error: Could not open $filename for writing."); 
} 
    else{
        fread($fp, filesize($filename));
        $accounts = explode("*@*", $theData);
        fclose($fp);
        for ($i = 0; $i <count($accounts); $i++){
                $items = explode("\n", $accounts[$i]);
                $date = $items[0];
                $user = $items[1];
                $post = $items[2];
            } 
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```